# How to add java project as library in android project using eclipse

Tags: android

Can anybody tell How to add java project as library in android project using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

As is explained in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), you can go into project properties (e.g., Project > Properties from the Eclipse main menu), go into the Android section of the properties dialog, and use the Add... button in the Library group box to pick an Android library project from the available libraries in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look here..

[Import source java project in Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736664/import-source-java-project-in-android-project)

Or you can create a jar file from your project and import it as external jar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694392/importing-external-jar-file-to-android-project)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For Library Project:
Rightclick->Properties->Android-> *tick Is Library*

For project in need of import:
Rightclick->Properties->Android->Add...->Library Project

Comment: By inference (since he is specifying "Android" specifically in the second set), tt looks like this is the same issue I am attempting to resolve - a non-Android java project used by an Android java project. There isn't an "Android" tab in a non-Android project.

Comment: I don't know how to, but this can probably link also against: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889572/android-project-referencing-normal-java-project-in-eclipse-since-sdk-tools-upd