# Using existing java code in Android Studio or eclipse

Tags: java, android, gwt

I am developing a word game. My aim is to have 90% of the code in pure Java, which is then referenced by Android Studio for an android app, by GWT to make a web solution and exported into objective C for iOS for the small amount of UI coding needed.

I have written all the code and I am only able to do this by manually copying the java classes between the projects. Clearly it must be possible as this seems such an obvious use case, but there does not seem to be a straightforward solution.

I realise I may be missing something. I have searched extensively, in particular the following:

[Import source java project in Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736664/import-source-java-project-in-android-project)

[Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try, and in what way did it fail? At least in Eclipse It should be fairly straightforward to set up an ordinary Java project and then either reference it as a project from your app project, or export it as a jar which you then put on the build path of your app project. Did you try any of these, and if so, what happened?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the mistake was mine. I have been though this again and I think it was my mistake. I can set up a project in Eclipse as an android library project and put all the standard code in there. I am able to reference this code from GWT, and the mistake I made was that in GWT we need to have the .client package which meant my library package was not enclosed. The solution was to include the .client in the library package.

Comment: Happy to hear that. For the sake of order please consider closing the question (preferably by answering it yourself and accepting that answer). Maybe it helps someone else.